# Video Player with Pyglet with Pyside/PyQt

Tags: pyqt4, media-player, pyside, pyglet

I would like to make a video player using Pyglet and Pyside.

(I can't use phonon because it requires the K-Lite Codec pack. With pyglet I can package avbin.dll)

I can get the audio of my movie to play, but I'm stuck on getting the video to show in the PySide dialog.

I think I need to use the player.get_texture() command, convert that to image data, then redraw the PySide widget background with that image. When trying this I just get a black image.

Here's my code:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import pyglet
import sys

class VideoPlayer(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.resize(600, 400)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: black")

        self.player = pyglet.media.Player()
        media = pyglet.media.load('test.avi')
        self.player.queue(media)
        self.player.play()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("Media Player")
    window = VideoPlayer()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's how I was trying to get the image from the pyglet player:

```
tex = self.player.get_texture().get_image_data() 
form = tex.format
pitch = tex.width * len(form)
pixels = tex.get_data(form, pitch)
img = QtGui.QImage()
img.loadFromData(pixels)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I was able to get the image from pyglet and turn it into a QImage()

```
tex = self.player.get_texture().get_image_data()
form = tex.format
pitch = tex.width * len(form)
pixels = tex.get_data(form, pitch)
img = QtGui.QImage(pixels, tex.width, tex.height, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB32)
img = img.rgbSwapped()
```